# Foreach loop of Eloquent relationship in Laravel view then changes any further results below it

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Eloquent relationship defined in the a Model.
In my Controller I am getting some profiles like so:

```
$profiles = $this->profileRepo->paginate('10');
```

In my view I make use of a relationship in the Profile model which gets the related images and user this in the foreach loop.
But then after this I try to get the Profile->nick_name and it won't work. I did a dd() and it shows the Model has now changed from Profile to the Image..

```
@foreach($profiles as $row)
  <div>
     @foreach($row->image->where('profile_picture', '1') as $row)
                <a href="$row->file">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </a>
     @endforeach
  </div>

  <div>
        //If this was ^^^Above^^^ the foreach() loop then it works fine :)
        <h3>{{ $row->nick_name }}</h3>
        <p>{{ $row->about }}</p>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Not sure why that happens or how to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner `foreach` loop overrides the `$row` variable.

Use a different variable in your inner loop:

```html
@foreach($profiles as $profile)
    <div>
        @foreach($profile->image->where('profile_picture', '1') as $image)
            <a href="{{ $image->file }}">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </a>
        @endforeach
    </div>

    <div>
        <h3>{{ $profile->nick_name }}</h3>
        <p>{{ $profile->about }}</p>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks mate :)